# Apache Tomcat Response time

Tags: apache, tomcat, response, httpresponse, server.xml

Currently we have an apache reverse proxy and tomcat in same machine.

I am interested to analyze the response time plotted by %D in tomcat.

1.I have understood that %D will include client network time and we have to use %F to get the accurate tomcat response time.

2.In my case apache forwards the request to tomcat using mod_proxy .So still my tomcat response time include client(user) network time or apache processing time.?

Comment: Tomcat has no clue how many layers outside of its influence you'd like to measure. The only thing it can measure is what happens within itself

Comment: From the [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html): `%D - Time taken to process the request, in millis`. It's the same case as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392625/why-is-ttfb-10x-nginx-total-request-time/68402917#68402917)